# How to print a Java List to a Yaml List in brace ([ ]) format, using Jackson yaml

Tags: java, list, serialization, jackson, yaml

I am trying to find a way to print Java ArrayLists to Yaml lists, in the following format:

```
[list-element1,list-element2,list-element3...]
```

However,I have only managed to print them into Yaml lists in the alternative format:

```
-list-element1
-list-element2
-list-element3
```

Is there a way that the first can be done with a *setting* in Jackson? I know it can be done with SnakeYaml, but do not want to follow this path.

In case the answer to this question is no, I also have created a custom serializer, which serializes the Java list to the desired format (`[list-element1,list-element2,list-element3...]`) and adds it to the jsonGenerator passed to the 
`serialize(...)` method by calling

```
jasonGenerator.writeStringField("ArrayList", list_string.toString()).
```

However, when I call

```
String yamlString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object_to_serialize)
```

the output is in the form of

```
'[list-element1,list-element2,list-element3...]'
```

(quoted), even though minimize quotes is enabled in the respective YAMLFactory.
Is there another solution, besides parsing yamlString and replacing the offending characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no other solution, and is most likely related to the process of java-to-yaml serialization. The same behavior is exhibited, not only when I try to output lists with brace characters, but also in strings containing colons, and in general it seems that whenever the library parses a string that violates some conditions (e.g beginning with blanks, or including a character that it uses for its yaml output), it wraps it with quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

[YAMLGenerator.Feature.CANONICAL_OUTPUT](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLGenerator.Feature.html#CANONICAL_OUTPUT) might help you:

```
YAMLFactory yf = new YAMLFactory();
yf.enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.CANONICAL_OUTPUT);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(yf);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(1,3,5)));
```

It will produce:

```
---
[
  "1",
  "3",
  "5",
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer Anton! It is close to what I would like, but not exactly. You see, quotes are still produced in the output (YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES will help in this case, but what if the elements to be written are not 1,3,5 but "TestElement1","TestElement2","TestElement3"). It would also be better if the whole result was in one line. Canonical Output proves to be problematic in other cases of the task as well - but thanks anyway!